# How do you access main activity from React-Native UI Component

Tags: android, react-native

I need to access the main Activity within a `SimpleViewManager` in order to utilise the android youtube player. However since 0.29, React-Native changes don't supply the main activity to the creation of modules.

I have read that we can now use `context.getCurrentActivity()`, however apparently you need to utilise Lifecycle events to make sure the activity is not `null`. I have tried adding these events by implementing `LifecycleEventListener`, however `onResume()` never gets called.

What I would like to understand is:

- When does the main activity get created?
- Why do we now need to use Lifecycle events to access a valid activity?
- Is there any documentation on these events?
- Is there any code that explains how to do this properly?

Comment: Not the complete solution. But ReactWebViewManager code is something you can look into. WebView internally requires activity to work. And ReactViewManager is using LifeCycle events and cleaning them up.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5707c3d9131941d71a313a3555b49f17097925a8/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java

Comment: Thanks, I'll take look. If I get anywhere I'll post some results here.

Comment: I also need this. Seems that since RN 0.33 you can call `getCurrentActivity` from `SimpleViewManager`, it was supposed to be available since 0.31 but seems there has been an issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9310. However I cannot update past 0.31 for the near future due to a library I am using.